# vim git gutter realtime update not working

Tags: git, vim

I'm trying to configure vim git-gutter in my terminal but I can't seem to enable the realtime functionality. 
It updates the gutter on save, it want the update to be realtime ( when I exit insert mode )

I added this to my .vimrc

```
let g:gitgutter_realtime = 0  
let g:gitgutter_eager = 0
```

I read on the docs that I should set updatetime to something lower, all tough this also doesn't seem to do anything:

```
set updatetime=250
```

How can I make it work real time ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those settings switch realtime **off**

https://github.com/airblade/vim-gitgutter/blob/master/README.mkd

Use `=1` there

> Note the realtime updating requires Vim 7.3.105 or higher.